# Bypass for cannot re-declare function

Tags: php

I am calling similar PHP scripts from different locations in WordPress.
They all have in common that they call another php file (genlib.php) which its some kind of library with a large number of php functions.

When I ran into the "cannot re-declare function ... in genlib.php" error, I wrapped each function into an "if !function_exists" condition to avoid this.

This is ugly because I have to do it so many times.

How can I avoid this on the level where I include the genlib.php file in my scripts?

Answer (score 4):

I believe using [`include_once`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [`require_once`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.require-once.php) in all files that include the file `genlib.php` should solve this problem.

**Update**: Based on the OP's comment, it appears that this solution does not work for multiple different scripts loading libraries which `include_once` `genlib.php`. In this case, the OP may have to regress to using a guard statement wrapping the entire `genlib.php`.

```
if (!defined('GEN_LIB_PHP')) {
  define('GEN_LIB_PHP', true);
  // Rest of code for genlib.php
}
```

Comment: This is not working because the first WP widget loads a script, which itself calls genlib.php via include_once.     And the same is true for a totally different script in WP widget #2.   I think it is not working because this is not inside the same script.

Comment: @mzurhorst, You might have to revert to doing C-style `#define` guards on the `genlib.php` in that case.

Comment: @mzurhorst, See this [question statement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2595171/391161) for how to do that in `genlib.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `include_once()` for the file. This prevents the system from running the code again, if the file was included before. The same applies for `requrie_once()`.